# to us vs to see us

Tags: word-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

Which sentence is grammatically correct or both?

> If he has time, he will come to us.

vs

> If he has time, he will come to see us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are *grammatically* correct, but with slightly different implied meanings.  #2 is more likely to convey the meaning you are intending to say.

> If he has time, he will come to us.

"He will come to us" is an idiomatic phrase that is used to emphasize "us" as a group being distinct from "he", and that there is a significant power imbalance between the two groups.  It strongly implies either that you intend to ambush him, either militarily or in a strong-arm business deal, or that he will come as a savior because "we" are in a dire situation and in need of great help.

> If he has time, he will come to see us.

"He will come to see us" is an idiomatic phrase that puts the emphasis on "see", meaning that there will be a friendly meeting.  No power imbalance is implied.  "See" definitely softens the phrase significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. Sentence #2 makes more sense and sounds better to me as a native English speaker, but both work.